# Add a checkbutton to the labelframe?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to realize the sample result, how to add a checkbutton to the labelframe, and if select the checkbutton, the frame will be enable, thank!
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/574NH.jpg)

Comment: I have solved it by using "-labelwidget".

Comment: That's the correct approach. Please write it up as an answer; it will help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw this question and Jimmy's comment that he had solved it, I was thinking that there should still be an explanation of how to do it. When I got around to doing it, Jimmy had already added such an explanation. I'm posting my suggestion anyway, in the hopes that it will be useful.

This answer is based partially on Jeremy Cowgar's example on the page http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/20054, under the button "Labelframes that enable their contents". I have simplified, restructured, and generalized the code a little bit, hopefully not introducing bugs while doing so. I have tried the code but not tested it thoroughly.

I have used "classic" widgets (in the namespace `tk`) in this example: just change the namespace to `ttk` (as in `ttk::labelframe`, etc) to get themed widgets. Sometimes more changes are needed as options or subcommands are different, but at least in the scope of this example they work the same.

The first object is to set up the `labelframe` that is going to be enable-able. It gets a `checkbutton` as labelwidget (by configuring the `-labelwidget` option): the checkbutton gets a global variable and a command script that calls a procedure. Only the labelframe needs to be managed (using `pack`, `grid` or whatever), it manages the checkbutton on its own. The checkbutton could have been made a child of `.greeter`, but this way it will be distinct from the widgets inside the labelframe.

```
tk::labelframe .greeter
tk::checkbutton .greeterEnabler -text {Say Hello} -variable greeterEnabled -command greeterEnablerAction
.greeter configure -labelwidget .greeterEnabler
pack .greeter -fill x -expand yes

proc greeterEnablerAction {} {
    if {$::greeterEnabled} {
        set state normal
    } else {
        set state disabled
    }
    foreach child [winfo children .greeter] {
        $child configure -state $state
    }
}
```

The labelframe is filled with widgets, only two in this example. They are made to be children of the labelframe, i.e. their window paths start with `.greeter`.

```
set greeterName World
tk::entry .greeter.name -textvariable greeterName

tk::button .greeter.button -text {Do It} -command {puts "Hello, $greeterName"}
```

The initial state of the labelframe is set. The `greeterEnablerAction` procedure could have been called directly instead of being called using `invoke`.

```
set greeterEnabled 1
.greeterEnabler invoke
```

The children of the labelframe need to be managed explicitly.

```
pack {*}[winfo children .greeter] -fill x
```

Widgets that are independent of the labelframe can also be added:

```
tk::button .bt2 -text Exit -command exit
pack .bt2 -fill x -expand yes
```

The complete program once again (the `Tk` package doesn't have to be required if the code is run in a Tk-enabled shell such as `wish`):

```
package require Tk

# set up the labelframe with a checkbutton as enabler
tk::labelframe .greeter
tk::checkbutton .greeterEnabler -text {Say Hello} -variable greeterEnabled -command greeterEnablerAction
.greeter configure -labelwidget .greeterEnabler
pack .greeter -fill x -expand yes

proc greeterEnablerAction {} {
    if {$::greeterEnabled} {
        set state normal
    } else {
        set state disabled
    }
    foreach child [winfo children .greeter] {
        $child configure -state $state
    }
}


# fill it with widgets
set greeterName World
tk::entry .greeter.name -textvariable greeterName

tk::button .greeter.button -text {Do It} -command {puts "Hello, $greeterName"}

set greeterEnabled 1
.greeterEnabler invoke

pack {*}[winfo children .greeter] -fill x

# this button is independent of the labelframe
tk::button .bt2 -text Exit -command exit
pack .bt2 -fill x -expand yes
```

Documentation:
[button (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/button.htm),
[checkbutton (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/checkbutton.htm),
[exit](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exit.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[labelframe (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/labelframe.htm),
[pack](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[winfo](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/winfo.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Great! Thanks for your so exhaustive and useful explanation! That's really let me benefit a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Donal's advice, list my solution below:

```
frame .f
labelframe .f.lf
checkbutton .f.lf.cb -text sample
label .f.lf.lb -text "This is for test"
.f.lf configure -labelwidget .f.lf.cb
pack .f
pack .f.lf
pack .f.lf.lb
```